# Fusion Table Response into HTML Table

Tags: php, html-table, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to get a Fusion Table SQL response into a basic HTML table.  This is for both search engine fodder and for use with google spreadsheets and their importhtml function.

The foreach to turn the response into a table are turning up some unusual responses, like 1 character at a time?  Also the response appears to be formatted as something that can easily be made into an array, but my efforts have been futile.  Have been working on this for over two days now, and I bet someone understands the formatting and knows the answer far better than I?

```
<?php
$result = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT%20*%20FROM%201QN6e86FybBULPekKvvXd_RF1jw01H7bZAJFjhUg&key=AIzaSyAm9yWCV7JPCTHCJut8whOjARd7pwROFDQ");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="page">
    <h1>A Table of Clicks</h1>

    <table class='data'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>date</th>
                <th>fundraiser</th>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>link</th>
                <th>price</th>
                <th>image</th>
                <th>ip</th>
                <th>merchant</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<?php
list($part1, $part2) = explode(' "rows": [[', $result);
$rows = explode('  ], [', $part2);
echo $rows[0]."<br>";
foreach ($rows as $row) {
{
//$array = array($row);
///var_dump($array);
$boxes = explode(",", $row);
    foreach ($boxes as $box) {
        echo "
        <tr>
        <td>".$box[0]."</td>
        <td>".$box[1]."</td>
        <td>".$box[2]."</td>
        <td>".$box[3]."</td>
        <td>".$box[4]."</td>
        <td>".$box[5]."</td>
        <td>".$box[6]."</td>
        <td>".$box[7]."</td>
        </tr>";
    }
    }
}
?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <hr />
    </div> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode` to parse the response(it's valid JSON):

```
<?php
$result = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT%20*%20FROM%201QN6e86FybBULPekKvvXd_RF1jw01H7bZAJFjhUg&key=AIzaSyAm9yWCV7JPCTHCJut8whOjARd7pwROFDQ");
$result=json_decode($result,true);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="page">
    <h1>A Table of Clicks</h1>

    <table class='data'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><?php echo implode('</th><th>',$result['columns']);?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php
            foreach($result['rows'] as $row){
              echo '<tr><td>'.implode('</td><td>',$row).'</td></tr>';
            }
          ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <hr />
    </div> 
</body>
```